# Datepicker date undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap-datepicker, and I'm getting this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

I don't think I have an old version of datepicker.js because I got the cdn from their website.

This is how I'm currently instantiating the datepicker and click event:

```
j('.fa-calendar').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d'
})

j(document).on('click', '.fa-calendar', function(){
    j('.fa-calendar').datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: Is there a missing semicolon after  j('.fa-calendar').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d'
  })

Comment: @lpg from what I've seen, that is the correct syntax for datepicker

Answer (score 0):

They should be working as in this example:

```js
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: '-3d'
})

$(document).on('click', '.fa-calendar', function(){
    $(this).closest('.input-group')
           .find('input.form-control')
           .datepicker("show");
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<p>start with datepicker:</p>
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" /><br/>

<p>start with icon:</p>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" >
  <span class="input-group-addon" >
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

**References**:

- [datepicker.css](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/css/datepicker.css)
- [bootstrap-datepicker.js](//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js)
- [Docs](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/)